# Compute the first digit of an integer in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a spreadsheet with column B having integers. I want to get the first digit of each entry in column B in the corresponding row of column C.

Comment: By integers, do you mean there are some negative values?

Answer (score 3):

If you want them as numbers for calculation to be done

```
=VALUE(LEFT(B1,1))
```

drag that down in Column C
 else

```
=LEFT(B1,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on @datatoo's answer, if your list includes negative values, you'll have to add a condition to look past any negative signs:

```
=VALUE(IF(B1<0,MID(B1,2,1),LEFT(B1,1)))
```

Comment: you COULD just take the absolute value of the cell first. abs()

Comment: @lornix Or that.... :P